# SFTP not transferring file using batch Script

Tags: batch-file, sftp, psftp

I´m trying to upload a file to a server using PSFTP, a script is generated automatically using batch scripting, the psftp is called at the batch script. But the file is not being uploaded and no errors are shown.

**FTP Script:**

```
lcd C:\files
cd / 
put file.txt    
exit
```

**FTP log:**

```
New local directory is C:\files
Remote directory is now /
local:file.txt => remote:/
```

As you can see at the FTP log the remote is empty and the file is not transferred.
But if we do the same commands manually (not executed in a batch script) the file is transferred correctly.

Please help us to find the root cause of this.

Comment: What happens after the `local:file.txt => remote:/`? Does `psftp` hang or exit? What if you add another command, like `ls`?

Comment: Hi Martin, thanks for answering. I have added the ls command, and the command is executed, but the file to be trasnferred is not shown, confirming that the file is not transferred

Comment: Can you show us screenshots of the console window for both the script test and manual test? Including the `ls` command?

Comment: Currently I´m not able to execute the commands manually, but basically the difference between sending the files manually and at the batch script is the next line: at batch script "local:file.txt => remote:/" (file not transferred), executing manually "local:file.txt => remote:/file.txt" (file transferred) , I will include the screenshots once I´m able to perform the commands

Comment: Did you try another SFTP client? For example with WinSCP you can do: `winscp.com /command "open sftp://username:password@example.com/" "lcd C:\files" "cd /" "put file.txt" "exit"`

Comment: Or you can actually use your psftp script like `winscp.com /script=c:\path\to\psftp.txt` (where `psftp.txt` is your "FTP script").

Comment: Hi all, we identified the root cause of the issue, the problem was caused by the psftp version while trying to call the ftp script: "psftp <connection details> -b <ftp_script>". So we only downloaded the latest psftp version, and now the file is transferred correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was caused by the psftp version, while trying to call the ftp script: "psftp  -b ".

So we only downloaded the latest psftp version, and now the file is transferred correctly.